# Where did I commit a mistake in calculating rotation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

[image]

I did something wrong in my calculation, can somebody tell me what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my limited understanding of German, I assume you are attempting to firstly compute the curl of a vector field, namely,

$$\vec{F}= \left( 
\begin{matrix}
2x \\
3z -xy \\
4yz -x
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

The curl can be seen as a cross product with a differential operator,

$$\nabla \times \vec{F}= \left( 
\begin{matrix}
\partial_y F_z -\partial_z F_y \\
\partial_z F_x - \partial_x F_z \\
\partial_x F_y -\partial_y F_x
\end{matrix}
\right) = \left( 
\begin{matrix}
(4z)-(3) \\
(0)-(-1) \\
(-y)-(0)
\end{matrix}
\right) = \left( 
\begin{matrix}
4z-3 \\
1 \\
-y
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

---

If you have troube memorizing the expression for the curl, recall the trick for the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix  by crossing diagonals. Alternatively, write out a form,

$$\omega = f(x,y,z) \, \mathrm{d}x + g(x,y,z) \, \mathrm{d}y + h(x,y,z) \, \mathrm{d}z$$

and take the exterior derivative, followed by applying the rules for interchanging wedge products.